# Get values of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to get numbers from

```
var arr = [1,[2],[[3]],[[[4]]]];
```

using JavaScript/jQuery.

could be more in the series.

Comment: use Array.prototype.reduce()

Comment: That is a horrible explanation of what you want to accomplish and doesn't identify any format for expected results. Please take the time to read [ask]. Also please show what you have tried...this isn't a free code writing service

Comment: Granted, the question is poor, but it's not a dup of the article linked by @Brian.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko very similar, but different. A multidimensional array is more complex than an array of arrays (n=2). The answer accepted there will not flatten the n=4 dim array from hemant, it needs more recursion

Comment: You forgot to show us all the code that you wrote and explain specifically what's not working with it.

Comment: @takendarkk you are mistaken, [that is not required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281)

Comment: Thank you John.
@charlietfl thank you. I tried for loop, for each and map method. Not to mention that it was silly hence I did not mentioned. I just needed a hint for the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Array.prototype.reduce()

For example:

```js
var arr = [1,[2],[[3]],[[[4]]]];

const flatten = arr => arr.reduce(
  (acc, val) => acc.concat(
    Array.isArray(val) ? flatten(val) : val
  ),
  []
);

console.log(flatten(arr));
```

Comment: it is good, i did not know this function (flatten) but neither I know ECMAScript 6. Can you please explain me this in ECMAScript 5?

Comment: @Hermant without the use of ES6 fat arrow functions, the code would be: `const flatten = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(
    function(acc, val) { 
      return acc.concat(
        Array.isArray(val) ? flatten(val) : val
      );
    },
    []
  );
};`

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, if you only want to get the numbers you can just convert the array to a string then use a simple regex to extract all of the numbers:

```js
console.log([1,[2],[[3]],[[[4]]]].toString().match(/\d+/g)); // ["1","2","3","4"]
```

If the result must be an array of numbers (not strings), you can use `Array#map` to run the conversion (`e => +e`).

```js
console.log([1,[2],[[3]],[[[4]]]].toString().match(/\d+/g).map(e => +e)); // [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: great solution, but critical assumption that strings are ok

Comment: @john edited to include example that returns numbers instead of strings.

Comment: Again, very good solution, but still has a restricted use case. You can't flatten a multidiminsional array of objects using a .match() approach, for example. If OP has your use case, yours is ideal, but a truly generic flatten needs something like Array.prototype.reduce()

Comment: @John Of course, if they are looking for anything other than just the numbers, then a recursive flattening will need to happen. As I said in the first sentence of my answer, this is only applicable if they only want to get the numbers.

Comment: Not really understanding the downvote here.

Comment: I sure didn't downvote. As I mentioned, I like your approach. let me upvote to balance it lol

Comment: toString worked good.